# Integral of smooth function over the unit n-ball

Tags: real-analysis, integration, analysis

I am interested in calculating the value of the integral

$$\int_{|\textbf{x}| < 1} e^{-\frac{1}{1+|\textbf{x}|^2}} \hspace{1.5pt} \text{d} \textbf{x}$$

where $|\textbf{x}|^2 = x_1^2 + x_2^2 + \cdots + x_n^2$ is the standard norm on $\mathbf{R}^n$. I appreciate any and all help!

Edit: there is probably no closed form. I am also interested in upper and lower bounds.

Comment: Have you tried polar coordinates?

Comment: I doubt the final integral is nice. After going to polar coordinates, you get $A_{n-1}\int_0^1e^{-\frac{1}{1+r^2}}r^{n-1}\,dr$, where $A_{n-1}=\frac{2\pi^{n/2}}{\Gamma\left(\frac{n}{2}\right)}$ is the surface area of the unit sphere $S^{n-1}$. Perhaps someone else knows more special functions to evaluate this (I tried some basic online calculators, and the non-premium version of Wolfram Alpha, and they gave up).

Comment: As peek-a-boo said, there probably is no nice closed-form. Given this, are you interested in lower or upper bounds?

Comment: Yes! I was waiting to see if someone knew of special functions that could be used, but I would be interested in bounds on the integral as well.